# LoginView with Success

Tags: python, django

I am currently working with my Django authentification app. My goal is once the user logged in successful I want to redirect it to the index page where my code shows a customised message:

```
messages.success(request, 'Login Successful', extra_tags='alert alert-dark')
```

My problem is I didn't manage to 'access' LoginView in my views.py.
I read about SuccessMessageMixin, but this LoginView won't work (Template Not Found):

```
class LoginView(auth_views.LoginView):
    template_name = "accounts/login.html"
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Only as long I include template_name in my urls.py it works, but I can't add the success message mixin there.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
]
```

Comment: where is your html placed? in the urls your filename ends with htm in the view with html. Paste the entire stack trace of error

Comment: Hi at14, sorry the htm was just a copy & paste error. I didn't paste the code for login.html as I thought it's not relevant. The template file works perfectly when I add it in the urlpatterns. I however don't understand how to 'link' it in the views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a custom `LoginView`, but in the urls.py you call ***auth_views***.LoginView.

To call your custom view you should do

```
from <module_name>.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

It's a good idea to have a different name for your custom view, i.e.*CustomLoginView*.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the followng snippet in the settings.py files:

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

You can add your own index page URL in 'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL' variable